# Powerpoint Macro-enabled Show Path

Tags: vba, path, save, powerpoint

I am trying to save a presentation as a macro-enabled show in PowerPoint, and I'm running into a problem when I do. This code that I'm using works great when I'm save as a presentation - but not as a show:

```
Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPRFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.PlaceholderFormat
Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue

'opening an existing presentation

Dim spath2 As String
Dim strpath2 As String
spath2 = ActivePresentation.Path <--
strpath2 = spath2 + "\Resources\AIT Diplomas\AIT Diplomas.pptx"
```

The problem is that when I save it as a macro-enabled show and try to run it, it stops at the <--- line of code because there "is no active presentation. When you save powerpoint as a macro-enabled show, then no "presentation" (powerpoint window) opens, just the slideshow window.

I need a way of finding the active show path that doesn't reference an activepresentation that doesn't exist.

Thank you for your time!

Respectfully,
Dustin

Comment: Have you tried `Application.Windows(1).Presentation.Path`?

Comment: @PatricK I just tried, and I'm getting this error: "Run-time error ' 2147188160 (80048240)':  DocumentWindows(unknown member) : Integer out of range. 1 is not in the valid range of 1 to 0.

Comment: Is it a powerpoint add-in/hidden presentation? What about `Application.Presentations(1).Path`? Can you show more code than just that "fault" line?

Comment: I've added more of the code above with a better explaination as to why activepresentation is not working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Steve helped me, here is the answer:

[.PPT macro-enabled show path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31030529/ppt-macro-enabled-show-path?noredirect=1#comment50198697_31030529)