# .PPT macro-enabled show path

Tags: vba, file, path, powerpoint, show

I am trying to save a presentation as a macro-enabled show in PowerPoint, and I'm running into a problem when I do. This code that I'm using **works great when I'm save as a macro-enabled presentation - but not as a macro-enabled show**:

```
Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPRFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.PlaceholderFormat
Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue

'opening an existing presentation

Dim spath2 As String
Dim strpath2 As String
spath2 = ActivePresentation.Path <--
strpath2 = spath2 + "\Resources\AIT Diplomas\AIT Diplomas.pptx"
```

The problem is that when I save it as a macro-enabled show and try to run it, it stops at the <--- line of code because there "is no active presentation. When you save powerpoint as a macro-enabled show, then no "presentation" (powerpoint window) opens, just the slideshow window.

I need a way of finding the active show path that doesn't reference an activepresentation, which doesn't exist.

Thank you for your time!

Respectfully, Dustin

Comment: Questions/Suggestions: Is this code supposed to be running from within an existing, running slide presentation or from within another application?   Use & instead of + for string concatenation or VB will bite you eventually.  Are you trying to save a macro-enabled presentation as a file with a .PPTX extension?  That won't work either.  PPTM or PPSM

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the reply. Thank you for the tip on the & instead of +.  I'm not trying to save the file in the code, I'm just working on it as a presentation, then I save it as a macro-enabled show, and I get the error above (because the show path goes into "C:...Microsoft Office\Excel"  instead of where the saved macro-enabled show was started from (which I'd like to overwrite).

Comment: It might be a good idea to post a bit more of the code ahead of the point where the error occurs, then.

Comment: That is the code unfortunately. It works when  presentation is open, but not macro-show without presentation. If you've powerpoint, open a new presentation and use the activepresentation.path to show the path in a msgbox. It will work fine. Then save as a macro-enabled show and it won't work. I'm trying to get around that.

Comment: See newly posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't answered my question about where the code is running FROM, I'm going to assume that it's from within PPT and that there are no other applications involved.  That being the case, this works fine, either from a PPTM or PPSM:

```
Sub MittedForYourApproval()

' if the code is running within PPT, you don't need to do it this way:
' PPT has a reference to itself.
'Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
'Dim oPPRFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
'Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.PlaceholderFormat
'Dim oPPTSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Dim oPPRFile As Presentation
' I don't know where you're going with this
' but PlaceholderFormat <> a shape
Dim oPPTShape As PlaceholderFormat
Dim oPPTSlide As Slide

'Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
'oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue

'opening an existing presentation

Dim spath2 As String
Dim strpath2 As String
spath2 = ActivePresentation.Path '<--
'strpath2 = spath2 + "\Resources\AIT Diplomas\AIT Diplomas.pptx"
MsgBox spath2

End Sub
```

Comment: Steve, that worked wonderfully. So that I can better understand, oPPRFile, oPPTShape, and oPPTSlide are just "waking up" a presentation?  I'm just curious to know how that fixed the problem :) Thank you so much!   P.S. It says I don't have enough reputation points to mark this as correct :/

Comment: oPPRFile, oPPTShape etc are object variables that hold references to a presentation, placeholder format and slide respectively.  As long as you're using them from within PPT itself, there's no need to start with a reference to the PPT application, since it's implicit.  To be honest, I can't say why it wouldn't have worked before.  Odd, isn't it?